# Typescript create a class from json

Tags: json, class, interface, typescript

I have an interface **IPost** and a class **Post**, I want to create Post from json data, in Post constructor I get the json response where the interface IPost matches it.

I mean IPost interface is generated by this great tool [json2ts](https://json2ts.dev/)

*json2ts : generate TypeScript interfaces from JSON*

```
import { IPost, Title, Guid, Content, Excerpt, Embedded, Links } from './Ipost.ts';

export class Post implements IPost {
    Id: number;
    Date: string;
    DateGmt: string;
    Guid: Guid;
    Modified: string;
    ModifiedGmt: string;
    Slug: string;
    Type: string;
    Link: string;
    Title: Title;
    Content: Content;
    Excerpt: Excerpt;
    Author: number;
    FeaturedImage: number;
    CommentStatus: string;
    PingStatus: string;
    Sticky: boolean;
    Format: string;
    Links: Links;
    Embedded: Embedded;

    constructor(json: any) {
        var self = this;
        json.subscribe(res => {
            var jsonRes: any = res.json();
            self = jsonRes;        //something like this
        });
    }
}
```

Can I assign the class `Post` to json directly since json is described the same as Post class!

Is there any other ways than assigning each property to its peer from json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you would JavaScript you'll have to iterate over each value, and assign that value to self, using standard loop.  Assigning to self in your case, simply changes the value of `self` to the `json` value, it doesn't make any changes `this` itself.

```
json.subscribe(res => {
    let json = res.json();
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
});
```

NOTE: `=>` binds `this` to the outer context (for example the class you're working with) to `this`, so that you do not need to the intermediate `self` variable.

Comment: `let obj = res.json()` instead of let json

Comment: I got nested properties in my interface, like `post.embedded.title.rendered`, does this work for all or I should create nested for loops for that?

Comment: If those nested properties are other class instances, then you would have to do it different yeah.